# Postgres permission denied for relation <table>

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to learn Postgres and Ive made two basic tables and I can't join them together.

here is my list Of relations:

```
 Schema |     Name     |   Type   |  Owner
--------+--------------+----------+----------
 public | login        | table    | postgres
 public | login_id_seq | sequence | postgres
 public | users        | table    | test
(3 rows)
```

When I use the command

```
SELECT * FROM users JOIN login ON users.name = login.name;
```

I get

> ERROR:  permission denied for relation login

I have no idea what to do or what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what I did to finally get it to work...I basically just went into the login properties on pgAdmin4, found the owner and switched it to test and ran:

 `SELECT * FROM users JOIN login ON users.name = login.name;`

and finally got what I was looking for. Surprisingly a simple fix.

Answer (score 4):

You should grant the `SELECT` permission to user *test*:

```
GRANT SELECT ON login TO test;
```

If if might allow *test* to modify `login`, you should grant other permissions as well:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON login TO test;
```

You should execute these statements as database owner or as user *postgres*. In general, you can use

```
psql -Upostgres -dtest
```

if you're running this command on the same machine where the Postgres server is running.

You may also change the ownership of `login` to *test*:

```
ALTER TABLE login OWNER TO test;
ALTER SEQUENCE login_id_seq OWNER TO test;
```

But have to execute this as user *postgres* as well.

**Edit**: You can try to change the user with

```
SET ROLE 'postgres';
```

as suggested by *@lat long*.

Comment: i get the same error of  ```permission denied for relation login```

Comment: What is the result of the `GRANT` statement, and what is the user you're connected with?

Comment: With the GRANT statement i get:
```permission denied for relation login```

my terminal says psql -U test. how would i figure out the user im connected with?

Comment: _test_ cannont grant permissions to a table that doesn't belong to him. You should connect as user _postgres_ with `psql -Upostgres -d<database name>`. This _should_ work if you're on the same server where the Postgres server is running.

Comment: I get 

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql"
LINE 1: psql -Upostgres -d test;
```

Comment: You have to run this command form **terminal**, or you might use `\c postgres` in `psql` to change the user from _test_ to _postgres_.

Comment: I've been running the commands from the terminal and i switched back to postgres=>  and once I use the command ``` psql -Upostgres -d test; ```

i get the same error of: 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql"
LINE 1: psql -Upostgres -d test;
             ^
```

Comment: If I run this command in `psql` I get exactly the error you described. This is no terminal error. Terminal would say something like `-bash: psql: command not found`. Please check this again. So how do you connect to the database otherwise? You may try this with user _postgres_, too.

Comment: I honestly thought when the pgAdmin is running, the database is already connected. I was doing a tutorial and of course at the last step, it wont go through. Is there a way to switch tables? One thing that confuses my is why in the relations, it says there is an owner of postgres when postgres doesnt have anything within that database. It was just a default one that I opened up the database with and then changed to test where all my tables are.

Comment: I don't use pgAdmin but I'm sure that you can change the user and other connection parameters in it. Please refer to its documentation. But you must already be logged in as postgres to create the login table. How did you manage that?

Answer (score 0):

The "test" user doesn't have permission to login and use the related tables. Run the query with the "postgres" user:

```
SET ROLE 'postgres';
```

Then run your query.

Comment: While changing the role with that command is helpful for modifying the tables, it isn't a good idea to use _postgres_ as an ordinary database user. Postgres has the permission to do everything like the root user on UNIX. As a postgres user you can easily and unintentionally destroy any schema elements.

Comment: Yes obviously it is not best practice. "test" user should be given privileges on the concerned table ideally.